# SD Card problems

Tags: external-sd, bugs

I am having an issue with my alcatel a30 tablet (9024w) and the problem is that when i format an sdcard as internal storage then remove it and insert it, i get a device missing warning telling me to reinsert the sdcard.

Comment: You remove the card while the device is up and running? If so, no wonder. Ever tried removing the (only) hard disk from a running PC? Making the card the *internal* storage, it is used as such and *must not be removed while the device is running.*

Comment: Well i wouldnt need to remove it if it worked but it wont show up

Comment: Then maybe you [edit] your question and include a more detailed description of the issue? Hard to help without having the full picture here. // PS: Is your issue the same as [adoptive sd card missing please re-insert](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/182925/16575)?

Comment: Glad to read, and thanks for the feedback! Mind to [answer your own question](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) with some details (especially useful if you have some hints; might help on the linked question as well)? Eg. whether it suddenly worked again after a reboot, or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought my sd card used and it turned out there was a master boot record that was messing with android